# Errors occurring when using list

Tags: vb.net

I have a list that I have entered five items into using this code:

```
     If (surname.Count + 1) < noofcompetitors Then
            surname.Add(txtSurname.Text)
     Else....
```

I am attempting to see these items using this code:

```
     Console.WriteLine(surname.Item(0))
     Console.WriteLine(surname.Item(1))
     Console.WriteLine(surname.Item(2))
     Console.WriteLine(surname.Item(3))
     Console.WriteLine(surname.Item(4))
```

However, I get the error 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'.

Comment: This is thrown by `Item()` when _"index is equal to or greater than Count."_ - add a check to verify the list has at least five items before accessing the values, or just use the debugger to how many there are. My money is on `If (surname.Count + 1) < noofcompetitors` as the culprit.

Comment: What is the value of `noofcompetitors`?

Comment: The value of noofcompetitors is 5

Comment: Does that help at all?

Comment: If `noofcompetitors` is 5, then as soon as `surname.Count` reaches the value of 4, then no more surnames will be added to the list.  If `surname.Count` is 4, then the valid indexes for the list are 0 - 3, so if you try to access `surname.Item(4)`, then you will get the exception.  Perhaps you should just use `If surname.Count < noofcompetitors` or `If (surname.Count + 1) <= noofcompetitors`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a for each loop?

```
    For Each name As String In surname
        Console.WriteLine(name)
    Next
```

That way you won't get the exception and you can see how many names are actually being added to your list

Comment: Cheers, that worked. It's only printing out 4 of the 5 names entered though, any idea what the cause of that could be?

Comment: @MyArmsFellOff If it's printing 4 names, there are only 4 names in the list. Check that you really added as many names as you think you did (the code in your question isn't enough to show that).

Comment: I'm not sure how you're adding these names to the list 5 times, but I assume it's in a loop? If that's the case, i would remove the +1. I think you're getting List.Count mixed up with the List's index property which starts at 0 where the count starts at 1.

Could you post more of the code to clarify?